# Translate Z Location of object for every frame?

Tags: objects, transforms, camera, keyframes

I am brand new to Blender and 3D modeling in general so please bear with me if I use incorrect jargon and terminology.

I got help from a friend making a video in Blender, but as I got further into the project I noticed the camera is to close on every frame. Sadly my friend went on vacation and is unavailable for a while so I have no source for help. To clarify I am looking for a way to change the Z location for every frame at the same time instead of going through and dragging the blue arrow frame by frame.

Any help is appreciated as I am going through multiple websites and only finding words and terms that don't make sense to me.

This is what I see on my screen, hoping it helps

[image: What my blender screen shows if it helps]

Comment: Are there any keyframes on the camera? If not, it should stay where you put it regardless of what frame you're on

Comment: i have 3 keyframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, but essentially you want to parent a camera to the path of the old camera. The easiest way to do this is to:

- duplicate the camera <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
- remove the keyframes on the second camera
- parent the second camera to the first camera <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- change the Transform widget orientation to Local
- move the second camera back on the local Z axis
- it will still move and pivot with the original camera's orientation.
- Select the second Camera and click Set Active Object as Camera <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>NUMPAD 0</kbd>
- you can also optionally hide the first camera via the outliner if you find it distracting

[image]

Comment: Thanks this was a big help! I have a few further questions if you don't mind. I just delete the old camera after this point correct? Does deleting that camera set the new camera to the main camera or do I have to change other settings to make it render from the new camera? Again, I am brand new to this and I greatly appreciate any help you are able to provide.

Comment: No, definitely don't delete the camera. The second camera is parented to the first camera, so all the animation data being used is the first camera's.  By parent the second camera to the first and sliding it along the z axis, we're effectively using the position and pivot point of the first camera without doing any complicated position value copying. You can hide the first camera, but don't delete it!

Comment: That makes a-lot of sense now that I think about it. Would hiding the camera make the video render from the new camera or do I have to change further settings?

Comment: You have to select the second camera and then do the Set Active Object as Camera command as I mentioned in the instructions. That makes it the render camera. You can hide the first camera with the H key but don't delete it.

Comment: I didn't notice the edit, sorry.

Comment: No problem, let me know if you get it working.

Comment: It looks like it has all worked, thank you very much.

Comment: Ok that's great. Please mark the answer as accepted if everything is working for you.